# Conversion from hex to decimal in ruby

Tags: ruby, integer, hex, ord

`0xFFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFE_FFFFFC2F.ord
=> 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663`

`0xFFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFF_FFFFFFFE_FFFFFC2F.to_i
=> 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663`

Could somebody explain me why both of these methods return the same integer value?
I'm not sure that i understand the method ord...

> Returns the codepoint of the first character of the string, assuming a single-byte character encoding"

I  found that, but here I've go a hex value and i used the method then get a decimal value, so "What the hex?" :D

PS: Is it decimal value for sure or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've quoted `String#ord` and here you call `#ord` on `Integer` - this value is not decimal, nor string, but integer.

[`Integer#ord` docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-ord):

> `ord → self`
>
> Returns the `int` itself.
>
> 97.ord   #=> 97
>   This method is intended for compatibility to character literals in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Okey... So after using a method ord on my hex, i've got still value in integer, right? How can i convert it to a decimal then ?

Comment: Hex is just a representation of an integer number. You can write it as hex or binary or decimal and it's still the same number.

Comment: So when i do calculation it's doesn't matter if i use a hex * decimal, because it's still the same number in integer ? We are talking about maths in ruby still.

Comment: @KarolMazurek: It doesn't matter how you write down the number 3. The number 3 is the number 3. Think about this: are the rules of mathematics different depending on whether you use your fingers or your toes to count?

Comment: @JörgWMittag you nailed it :D

Comment: If it helps, pls consider accepting and upvoting the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, i will do it for sure, but i,ve just joined the stack and need 15+ rep to do this

Comment: You can approve even now (and you'll get some rep for that)